# Prove that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $0 < N^{-1} < b-a$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers

Given are two numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$. Prove that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $N \geq 1$ with

$$0 < N^{-1} < b-a.$$
Show that there exists a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with

$$ \frac{k}{N} \in (a,b).$$

Choosing $N = \frac{2}{b-a}$. gives $N^{-1} = \frac{b-a}{2}$ and from that follows $0 < N^{-1} < b-a$.

But now I don't know how I can prove that there exists a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with

$$ \frac{k}{N} \in (a,b).$$

I know that $\frac{k}{N} = k \cdot \frac{2}{b-a}$, so I need to find a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with

$$a < \frac{2k}{b-a} < b,$$
but I don't know how to find such $k$.

Comment: On the first part: You can take $\frac{1}{\lfloor b - a \rfloor + 1}$ and the inequality becomes strict.

Comment: @DWe1 how is $N = \frac{1}{\lfloor b-a \rfloor +1}$ satisfies $0 < N^{-1} < b-a.$ ?

Comment: @Philip you can not set $N = 2/(b-a)$ because it might not be a whole number. Also you can comment instead of changing your question.

Comment: @Babydesta, I think that $\lfloor{1\over b-a}\rfloor+1$ was intended.

Comment: @BarryCipra I do not think that works either. take $b = 3$ and $a = 2$, then "N=2"

Comment: @BarryCipra that's right, sorry about the mistake.

Comment: @Babydesta, I think you're wrong about that. $N=\lfloor1/(b-a)\rfloor+1\implies\lfloor1/(b-a)\rfloor=N-1\implies1/(b-a)\lt N\implies1/N\lt b-a$.

Comment: What if $N = 2/ \lceil b-a \rceil $?

Comment: @PhillipJones, that won't work if $b-a\lt1/2$, since the ceiling function is $1$ in that case, giving $N=2$.

Answer (score 1):

FIRST PART:

We assume the following theorem

Which is a corollary of [Archimedean Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)

```
Given a positive real number then there exist a less positive rational number.
```

That is 
$$0 < r/s < \alpha$$

Now if 
$b-a = \alpha$, then choose $N = s$
. Using our assumption 
$$0< 1/s = N^{-1} < r/s < \alpha = b-a$$

SECOND PART:

$$1/s < b-a$$
$$(as+1)/s < b$$
$$as/s < (as+1)/s < b$$
Choose $K = aN+1$

Comment: I don't remember the name of the theorem I used but [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-that-between-two-real-numbers-there-are-infinitely-many-rationals?) might help, it follows from the theorem that there is a rational number between two real numbers

Comment: That's Archimedean property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property

Comment: Thanks @martycohen,

Comment: @Babydesta but for $K=aN +1$ with $a$ a real number, $K$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}$?